# Oracle XMLTable and Create Table As Syntax Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, xmltable

I'm trying to `create table as` from an XMLTable type in order to split a column that has comma-separated values into multiple rows but getting an error about the syntax being incorrect.

My statement looks something like

```
create table XX as (
select * from yy, xmltable(('"' || replace(csv_separated_list, ',', '","') || '"'))
)
```

If I run the select subquery it works as expected... so it looks like it has something to do with the create table as statement wrapping it.

Comment: Please share the whole statement that is erroring and the whole error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The value extracted from the dummy XML is not a string, although your client may display it as if is one. The `dump()` function reports it as type 58, [which is an opaque type](https://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/oracle-type-code-mappings/). There is an implicit conversion from that to the XMLType data type allowed for a table column; which is throwing an XML processing error, since that value is not itself valid XML.

You can cast it to a string type:

```
create table XX as
select yy.*, cast(x.column_value as varchar2(30)) as value
from yy
cross join xmltable(('"' || replace(csv_separated_list, ',', '","') || '"')) x
```

Or specify the data type in the xmltable:

```
create table XX as
select yy.*, x.value
from yy
cross join xmltable(('"' || replace(csv_separated_list, ',', '","') || '"')
  columns value varchar2(30) path '.') x
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08a0b9f4c4031666ce78d9651928c64f)